# How to close current(parent) window after redirecting to third party url

Tags: javascript

By clicking on the submit button I'm redirecting to third party url, now at the same time I want to close the existing(parent) window.
Can anyone help me on the same?

Comment: Why not redirect to the third party URL from the current window?

Comment: They were not accepting if I am redirecting to url in current window, they want to redirect and close current window.

Comment: You won't be able to close the current window if it is not originally opened by Javascript. If it is, you can simply call `window.close()` to close the current window. Also, I vaguely remember that some browsers are planning to disallow things like "open a new tab and close current", because those patterns are generally used by spammy advertisements.